# Bind Mounting across different file systems

Tags: linux, mount, bind-mount

Does the command `mount -o bind` allow mounting a folder from a different file system (vfat, ntfs) to a folder in Linux native partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Well, I've made a quick test on my system, mounting a NTFS partition from Windows onto a directory in a XFS Linux partition, and it worked okay.

You have to do this operation as root.

Comment: You needn't do it as root if the bind mount is specified in `/etc/fstab` for the user attempting to do it. Like `/path/to/source/folder /path/to/target/folder bind noauto,user 0 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. The main point is that the source and destination folders have to exist prior to attempting the mount. You also need to be superuser.

Also read up on bind-mounts, as there are options to them too.

Comment: The target dir can be created as a consequence of the mount action with `mount -o bind,x-mount.mkdir[=mode]` which actually *does* require root auth to do, but bind mounts can be specified in `/etc/fstab` otherwise. The `x-*` options to `mount` can be used to signal a monitoring process though which will handle that as well.

Comment: @mikeserv: nice, wasn't aware of the `x-*` option. A reminder to sometimes skim over `man` pages again after a new installation.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, and I'm betting that `x-*` stuff could be pretty useful if a monitoring script watched mounts with a `findmnt -poll`...